Default React Native App not building(Android)
I have been trying to setup a new react-native project from the reactnative.dev website for the past 8 hrs. I have setup the environment is instructed but the app is not building. Here are some details:
Environment:
Operating System: macOS
platform: Android
Here is the error log:

Here's the log for react-native doctor:

Here's the error log building it in Android Studio:

How do I resolve this error.
